# How to get list of json strings from sinlgle line multi json string in scala

Tags: json, string, scala

I am trying to get list of json string from given string having multiple json strings separated by ",".

For example
    val jsonString = "{\"a\":\"b\"},{\"c\":\"d\", \"e\":\"f\"}"

```
expected result , List[String] :
["{\"a\":\"b\"}", "{\"c\":\"d\", \"e\":\"f\"}"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution for it.

```
val jsonString = "{\"a\":\"b\"},{\"c\":\"d\", \"e\":\"f\"}"
val jsonListString = "[" + jsonString + "]"
val jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonListString)
```

This will create array of json.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the json separator with a `string` or `character` that is not repeated in the whole string and use that special separator to be used with `split` method to get you your required output. Here I have used `-`

```
jsonString.replace("},{", "}-{").split("-")
```

You should have output as

```
res0: Array[String] = Array({"a":"b"}, {"c":"d", "e":"f"})
```

One step further, calling `toList` method would get you to the final *dataType* you require

```
jsonString.replace("},{", "}-{").split("-").toList  //res0: List[String] = List({"a":"b"}, {"c":"d", "e":"f"})
```

Comment: can you share your input string ? use the one i mentioned.

Comment: I used the one you've mentioned `val jsonString = "{\"a\":\"b\"},{\"c\":\d\", \"e\":\"f\"}"`

Comment: stange there are 2 "," in the string So it should have created three strings out of it.

Comment: there are three strings. first one is `{"a":"b"}` second one is `{"c":"d"` and the third one is `"e":"f"}`

Comment: Oh sorry i missed it. 
Exactly,  i want to separate out json strings individualy.

Comment: check the expected result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160810/discussion-between-abhishek-tripathi-and-ramesh-maharjan).